# Ember-CLI and Rails: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

I am trying to build an app with Ember-CLI (ember.js) and Rails 4.2.0.  I am keeping the Ember and Rails codebases separate, so I have enabled CORS with the rack-cors gem.  I keep getting the following errors when the Ember app makes a request to the Rails api:

```
406 Not Acceptable
```

And:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And this on the Rails side:

```
Processing by CustomersController#index as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

The request Accept header is:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

And my controller action is:

```
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @customers }
      #format.js { render json: @customers } Tried this too
    end
  end
```

I also have a customer_serializer using the active_model_serializer gem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’ve never used `rack-cors` but it doesn’t appear to be working. Is there actually an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the response from Rails?

Comment: Without :defaults => { :format => :json } on my customers route, the header was not being set.  This fixed it.  Don't really understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My customers routes needed :defaults => { :format => :json }

```
resources :customers, :defaults => { :format => :json }
```

With that it works!

Answer (score 2):

I use [rails-csrf](https://github.com/abuiles/rails-csrf) on ember to add a X-CSRF-Token to all my requests, rails looks for this by default so you only have to send the csrf token to ember to make this work (no need for more gems on rails side). 
First you need to install the rails-csrf npm package. In your ember cli folder run:

```
npm install rails-csrf --save
```

Then add the initializer to the app/app.js file:

```
loadInitializers(App, 'rails-csrf');
```

Then you will have to generate an application route:

```
ember generate route application
```

And add a before_model to it:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    return this.csrf.fetchToken();
  }
});
```

if you started the ember server with the --proxy http://localhost:3000 option then  fetchToken will look for your csrf token in http://localhost:3000/api/csrf by default. So you will need to add a route and controller on your rails side.

First add a namespaced route to your config/routes.rb file

```
namespace :api do
  get :csrf, to: 'csrf#index'
end
```

Then add the csrf controller inside app/controllers/api/csrf_controller.rb

```
class Api::CsrfController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: { request_forgery_protection_token => form_authenticity_token }.to_json
  end
end
```

Now if you have rails running and open http://localhost:3000/api/csrf url in your browser you should see the json hash with the csrf token. Now all ember's requests to the proxy server will have the csrf token set in the X-CSRF-Token which rails look fore by default.

That should be it, just remember to make sure you start the ember server with the proxy set to your rails server, and that rails is also on.

Comment: In application_controller.rb, I have the following: protect_from_forgery with:  :null_session so I do not think CSRF is the problem.  Are you sure I need this package?  It is not mentioned in the Ember-CLI + Rails tutorial: https://www.devmynd.com/blog/2014-7-rails-ember-js-with-the-ember-cli-redux

Comment: oh if you disable protect_from_forgery you don't need any of that hahaha. try to start your rails server like this: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 and the ember server: ember s --proxy http://localhost:3000

Comment: That did not work.  Thank you for help though.  This has now cost me a few hours and counting!